# Point orientation relative to a line

Tags: java, android, geometry

I'm trying to write a method in java that determines the orientation of a position relative to a line.

A little context:  (Not necessary for the answer but may be helpful) 
I'm working on collision detection for a ball on body parts on a player. The player has a head chest knee ankle and toe, all defined as having a position and a tether position. For example the tether position for head would be chest, for the chest it would be the position of the player(or the hips) and so on.

For collision detection I currently have a function written that determines the distance between the ball and the body parts, but this fails to catch when the body part is dragged too quickly and skips over the ball.

I have methods in each body part class that is supposed to determine the orientation of a position relative to that body part.

The methods I wrote call this getAngle method: 
pivotPos and basePos are the base line, and the Position the method is called with

```
public double getAngle(Position basePos, Position pivotPos) {
    double baseAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
            pivotPos.getY() - basePos.getY(),
            pivotPos.getX() - basePos.getX())) + 180;
    double otherAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
            this.getY() - pivotPos.getY(), this.getX() - pivotPos.getX()));
    return baseAngle - otherAngle;
}
```

This is what I have written for the chest and head.

```
@Override
public int isOnGoodSide(Position p, double radius) {
    double angle1 = p.getAngle(tetherPosition, position);
    double angle2 = p.getAngle(position, tetherPosition);
    if (angle1 >= 270 && angle2 <= 90) {
        if (p.distanceBetweenPointAndLine(tetherPosition, position) > radius) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    } else if (angle1 <= 90 && angle2 >= 270) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have written for Knee Ankle and Toe

```
@Override
public int isOnGoodSide(Position p, double radius) {
    double angle1 = p.getAngle(position, tetherPosition);
    double angle2 = p.getAngle(tetherPosition, position);
    if (angle2 <= 90 && angle1 >= 270) {
        if (p.distanceBetweenPointAndLine(tetherPosition, position) > radius){
            return 1;   
        }
        return -1;
    } else if (angle2 >= 270 && angle1 <= 90) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is part of the test cases.

```
public void test_isOnGoodSide() {
    Position pos1 = new Position(10, 10);
    Position pos2 = new Position(20, 10);

    // Horizontal line
    Position pos7 = new Position(15, 15);
    Position pos8 = new Position(15, 5);
    Position pos9 = new Position(5, 100);
    Position pos10 = new Position(25, 20);

    Knee knee1 = new Knee(pos1, pos2);
    assertEquals(1, knee1.isOnGoodSide(pos7, 0));
    assertEquals(-1, knee1.isOnGoodSide(pos8, 0));
    assertEquals(0, knee1.isOnGoodSide(pos9, 0));
    assertEquals(0, knee1.isOnGoodSide(pos10, 0));
```

Basically these methods done work, I have plenty of test cases but cant figure out my error. If you see what is wrong with my code or can offer another solution that would be helpful. I also tried to read through Jon Shewchuk's "Fast Robust Predicates for Computational Geometry" but I couldn't understand it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the question? (is it the ball skipping problem?) if yes then either you solve collision skip algebraically (which is too much for you right now from the state of your code I think) or on any drag do not move body part directly to destination , instead iterate it with few steps (the more there are the less chance to skip). for example you draw arm 100px up so what you actually do is drag 10 times 10px up instead ...